# ¿ Por que mi programa da como respuesta nan?

Tags: c++

Hola soy nuevo y estoy aprendiendo c++, pero por alguna razón el resultado de código da "nan", les agradecería si me pueden ayudar, gracias.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std; 

int main(){
    //ax^2+bx+c=0
    float a, b, c, resultado1, resultado2;
    
    cout<<"Digite el valor de a: "; cin>>a;
    cout<<"Digite el valor de b: "; cin>>b;
    cout<<"Digite el valor de c: "; cin>>c;
    
    resultado1 = (-b+((sqrt(pow(b,2))-(4*a*c))))/(2*a);
    resultado2 = (-b-((sqrt(pow(b,2))-(4*a*c))))/(2*a);
    
    cout<<"\nEl resultado con simbolo positivo es: "<<resultado1<<endl;
    cout<<"El resultado con simbolo negativo es: "<<resultado2<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Recuerda que las raíces cuadradas no se aplican a números negativos

Comment: Lo he probado y funciona bien, quizás sea como dice @Japv, debes tener cuidado de los signos.

Comment: Ah okay muchas gracias capo

Answer (score 6):

Por lo que veo, estás resolviendo una ecuación de tercer grado. El problema es que no todas las ecuaciones de tercer grado tienen una solución real. Por ejemplo, para ***x<sup>2</sup> – 2x – 8*** las dos soluciones son -2 y 4, pero para ***2x<sup>2</sup> – 2x + 5*** las soluciones son [imaginarias](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_imaginario).

Es por eso que tu resultado es NaN, ya que un número imaginario no es un número real, y ese es el significado de NaN: ***N**ot **a** **N**umber*.

---

La solución al problema es muy sencilla, en lugar de hacer la raíz cuadrada sobre un número real, hazla sobre un número [complejo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_complejo):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    float a, b, c;

    cout << "Digite el valor de a: "; cin >> a;
    cout << "Digite el valor de b: "; cin >> b;
    cout << "Digite el valor de c: "; cin >> c;

    auto resultado1 = (-b + sqrt(complex<float>((b * b)) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);
    auto resultado2 = (-b - sqrt(complex<float>((b * b)) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);

    cout << "\nEl resultado con simbolo positivo es: " << resultado1 << endl;
    cout << "El resultado con simbolo negativo es: " << resultado2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[El código anterior muestra](https://tio.run/##nZDNSsQwFIXXk6c4jJtUp6hFN7Z2pW/h5iaNnUB@apMMgvjsNR0GWoVRcHHhnsPh454rh6GUhlw/TRfaSZM6hUb7EEdFtmWLJy3F/TfD28Go95Yx7SIsaccL9sE2KWjXw5FVYSCpEGJXM7Z5NZ4iaAexg5wN6VNE02D7pHsdFZTBgYwfkeH0gG0NqR3aFlT/HhbrsPgjLNfh4x2UoseoQjKROn@LR/BS4ArhbYz8VLI5Xt9yLnAJURQowe/ySnlkkfU1eDXrov4JrE7A8t/AVaEX92wWNKR3CNoKbzwGH3TUBw8VcsU5veqUlXKdWf/mLMipns6AqgXENqOKaXS4qdnnNFWsYvfsCw):

> ```
> El resultado con simbolo positivo es: (-0.5,1.5)
> El resultado con simbolo negativo es: (-0.5,-1.5)
> ```

Para a = 2, b = 2 y c = 5, sin usar `std::complex` el resultado sería:

> ```
> El resultado con simbolo positivo es: -nan
> El resultado con simbolo negativo es: -nan
> ```

Si no quieres ver los números en formato complejo, puedes personalizar la salida con una función:

```
void muestra(const std::complex<float> &complejo)
{
    if (complejo.imag() != .0f)
        std::cout << "No tiene solucion\n";
    else
        std::cout << complejo.real() << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas, nan significa "not a number", es decir, no es un número. Esto suele ocurrir en divisiones por 0 o raíces cuadradas negativas. Tu problema tiene un problema y es muy gordo. Es que tú debes de realizar varias comprobaciones para realizar esas operaciones.

Por ejemplo si le das de valor a=5, b=6, c=4:
Lo que ocurre es que b*b=36, pero 4*5*4=80. Por tanto no puedes hacer la raíz cuadrada de 36-80.
Para solucionarlo tendrías que estudiar todos los casos en los que te ocurran estos problemas matemáticos y solucionarlos mediante un if.
En este caso sería: if(b>a)...

Para más información busca en google acerca de este ejercicio, es muy típico para realizar muchas sentencias condicionales. Un saludo.